# Не отображается содержимое блока выезжающего меню в Safari из-за стандартной навигации внизу браузера

Tags: css3, html5

Вопрос в теме. При клике в хедере города > все города - выезжает справа меню с выбором города. Внизу его есть 2 кнопки: применить и сбросить. Только на safari они изначально не видны, а отображаются только после полной прокрутки списка городов или смены ориентации на мобильном устройстве.
Изначально этот блок position: fixed;
На Android все хорошо. Знаю что принято писать код, но для тестирования закинул на хост чтобы могли просмотреть на устройствах: [ссылка](http://test3.dtraduga.vh66.hosterby.com/public/assets/templates/index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"left:0;" добавьте к стилям .navigation-lm

Comment: я у себя такого класса даже не нахожу? или это что-то стандартное от safari?
попробовал просто дописать, но ничего не поменялось (

Comment: я про класс не писал ничего. Добавить к стилям!

<div class="navigation-lm" style="
    position: fixed;
    /* bottom: 00px; */
    display: flex;
    bottom: 0;
    color: red;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    left: 0;
    ">Применить</div>

Comment: добавил, но не помогло (

Comment: почему не помогло? только что загрузил вашу ссылку в сафари и кнопка "применить" видна

Comment: а у меня нет(... только когда доскролишь или сменишь ориентацию
вы с мобильного устройства смотрите?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/KC56THnh2Nn0Rw - видео с экрана. вы страницу перегружали? проверили, что стиль обновился?

Comment: я смотрю на iphone 5... это про меню слева, когда на бургер нажимаешь... это я там тестировать начал потом... изначально эта проблема у меня была при выборе города: город - все города и там вменю снизу 2 кнопки (сбросить и применить) ((

Comment: проверил только что на iphone8 - кнопка показывается. скорее всего, ваш айфон закешировал страницы и не подгрузил изменения. сейчас еще в эмуляторе iphone5 посмотрю

Comment: у вас и в бургере и в городах отображаются кнопки внизу?

Comment: Так. Давайте по другому. Во-первых, вам просто надо, чтобы кнопки отображались внизу всегда, поверх промотки списка или должны быть после списка?

Comment: Получается есть меню открывающееся по клику и справа и слева. Они просто немного по разному реализованы. В меню справа есть список с вариантами выбора города. При открытии меню появляется список с городами, напротив каждого стоит radio для выбора. Внизу всегда отображается блок с кнопкой применить. Даже если только открыли список и выбрали первый город. Должны быть после списка. Это как навигационное меню к списку.

Comment: поставьте такие стили для .navigation-right-menu

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100px;
    
    
    border: 0;
    background: #fff;
    color: #fff;

и потом напишите, проверить

Comment: добавил, - можно проверить

Comment: class .navigation-right-menu - не вижу изменений. сделайте для этого класса те стили, что я указал.

Comment: пересохранил еще раз

Comment: Не знаю куда вы сохраняете, но явно не куда надо. Сами посмотрите: откройте правое меню и блок для кнопок с классом .navigation-right-menu - для этого класса, как было position: fixed, так и осталось. В общем ладно, вкратце  один из вариантов что сделать: не использовать position: fixed, а использовать для меню position: relative, а для блока кнопок: position: absolute; опускать блок кнопок bottom:0;left:0;right:0;height:100px; а для списка городов сделать нижний отступ на высоту блока кнопок. Переносите в песочницу (codepen.io, например) ваш код, а то так через чат трудно и долго объяснять

Comment: я затупил, там дублировалось в медиа запросе - пересохранил еще раз

Comment: Ну вы бы хоть проверили. Нет ничего. Все. Хотите продолжить - дублируйте код меню в песочницу, так дело не пойдет, у меня тут свои задачи то же есть

Comment: вот примерно так можно сделать, изучайте и внедряйте к себе: https://codepen.io/Firsov36/pen/vYOepVB (высоту меню в 250px сделал специально, чтобы прокрутка пунктов меню появилась)

Comment: хорошо, я попробую, спасибо большое

Comment: Я тут подумал, а зачем вообще заморачиваться с этим позиционированием блоков, когда можно намного легче все сделать flexbox'ом: https://codepen.io/Firsov36/pen/VwLMQqm

Comment: Попробую ваш вариант. На iphone у вас хорошо работает?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/3NzlcOF6iaLITQ - вот видео симултора айфона

Comment: а что такое "&>"

Comment: код scss, интерпретируется в обычный css как `.menu .menu-items>li` , но это уже не тема данного вопроса))